# Pass in 127.0.0.1 to RPC client

Tags: c, rpc

I followed the simple example of creating RPC client and server [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-xtVoKoH1M). Basically, the steps are:

1. Create a valid .x file--in this case, add.x
2. rpcgen -a -C add.x
3. add a printf() line in add_server.c to check whether the server gets the client request
4. make -f Makefile.add
5. ./addserver
6. in another terminal, run ./addclient localhost

This should print something in the first terminal, but it doesn't seem to print anything in my case. I am running the codes on a school server by using ssh. Perhaps I should specify the port, i.e., 127.0.0.1? Regardless, I'm not sure if this will solve the problem. Any ideas?

---

The code for add.x is:

```
struct numbers {
    int num1;
    int num2;
};

program ADDITION {
    version ADDITION_1 {
        int ADD(numbers)=1;
    } = 1;
} = 0x2fffffff;
```

All the other files are generated by rpcgen from add.x

---

The printf() addition in add_server.c is:

```
/*
 * This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
 * These are only templates and you can use them
 * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include "add.h"

int *
add_1_svc(numbers *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{

    static int  result;

    /*
     * insert server code here
     */
    printf("Got the client request!");
    return(&result);
}
```

Comment: The port is a connection point on a computer (HTTP usually uses port 80, for example), not an IP address, so ignore that.  Does `rpcinfo` tell you anything?  Beyond that, without the code, it's going to be really hard to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: yes, rpcinfo does tell me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh!  The RPC server is buffering its output.  I found it by digging into the `add_svc.c` code to add debugging statements.  Printing something *after* the call to the remote call fixed it.

That's a terrible solution, though, because that code is automatically generated.

Instead, you have two choices.

- After your `printf()` call, flush the output buffers with `fflush(stdout);`
- Add a carriage return (`\n`) to the end of your output string.

Either will work fine.

For the reasons behind this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).